# Help with Syncing Geth: 1.8.23

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, fast-sync

I am not sure if I'm alone in this but it seems that the latest Geth client is very slow.

I tried posting the issue on Geth's github page but it got closed almost immediately and no one is replying to it anymore.

This is [my original issue](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/19167)

Problem is that this is the first time I ever suffered with syncing Geth, all previous clients synced fine, I've been spinning nodes for over a year now on both testnets and mainnet hosted on AWS EC2 instances and never had any issues whatsoever.

I have now started 3 instances running Geth v1.8.23 hoping one of them will sync but to no avail. All three nodes attached to an IOPS optimized EBS volume with 6000 IOPS and all three are c5.2xlarge instances, thats 8 vCPUs and 15GB of RAM which is frankly an overkill.

Yet geth still fails to sync and always 100 blocks behind. This is the `eth.syncing` result from one of my nodes a couple of seconds ago:

```
{
  currentBlock: 7278405,
  highestBlock: 7278488,
  knownStates: 274903276,
  pulledStates: 274894571,
  startingBlock: 0
}
```

Has anyone successfully started a Geth 1.8.23 node? Anything special I need to do before I start this latest client version?

Note that I need a full node, a light node wont serve my purpose.

Answer (score 1):

USE PARITY instead of GETH
We started geth many times but it stucked after sometime and we have need to restart ever but in parity case it's working fine.